# Gmail API permission to send emails on user consent in my react-redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, gmail-api

I am working on a react-redux application where the user can submit their feedback/complaint to respective organization. The idea is to send emails on user's consent for which I am using Gmail API. I have integrated a feedback form.

Now the user has to be logged in before submission of the message. I do not want to add Gmail send (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send) scope with login. Login(on the header) only works with the profile and read-only scopes. Send email permission should only be asked separately when submit is clicked and then take further action on that consent. How can I achieve this send email scope separately? I am writing down my login code as I am not sure what has to be done on submit.

```
var clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';                    
var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly '+'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile';

var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

componentDidMount() {
  this.handleClientLoad();
}


 handleClientLoad = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js";

  script.async = true
  script.onload = () => {
    window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      window.gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
      window.setTimeout(this.initClient(), 1);
    });
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}

initClient = () => {
window.gapi.client.init({
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  clientId: clientId,
  scope: scopes,
}).then(() => {
window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus());
      this.updateSigninStatus(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
  }

updateSigninStatus = (isSignedIn) => {
if (isSignedIn) {
  window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.listen((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });
} else {
    console.log("error");
  }
 }

authClick = () => {
    window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then((user) =>
       console.log(user)
 )}
```

Following is the order:

1. User logs in
2. Fill out the feedback form
3. Hit submit (ask user's consent using Gmail send scope)
4. Perform actions on the basis of consent.

I am stuck on the 3rd step. How to add scope separately to get user consent?

Answer (score 0):

you cant your going to need to request consent at the time you authenticate your user.  You cant split that up.

You will need to add the Gmail.send scope here.

```
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly '+'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile';
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. Actually, we can request additional scopes at such points and there's even a documentation for that. Please follow this link to know more: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth.